# Ordenar array multidimensional por campo

Tags: php

No acabo de entender la documentación de PHP para ordenador un array multidimensional por un campo. En mi caso tengo el siguiente array y quiero ordenarlo por tipología, siendo asociativo:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(90) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(29) "Sniper Ghost Warrior 2 - Gold"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(11) "Complemento"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(90) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(16) "MK14 EBR & skins"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(11) "Juego"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(90) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(15) "Limited Edition"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(11) "Complemento"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; "
  }
  [4]=>
  array(90) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(15) "Snipter Ghost Warrior Pase de Temporada"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(11) "Juego"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435957d4; "
  }
```

Quiero que primero me aparezcan los de la tipología "Juego", aunque eso tengo entendido que se puede elegir entre `SORT_ASC` o `SORT_DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `ursort`

Sea tu array:

```
$miarray = [
  [
    "Juego"=> "Sniper Ghost Warrior 2 - Gold",
    "Tipologia"=> "Complemento",
    "Pertenece"=> "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; ",
  ],
  [
    "Juego"=> "MK14 EBR & skins",
    "Tipologia"=> "Juego",
    "Pertenece"=> "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; ",
  ],
  [
    "Juego"=> "Limited Edition",
    "Tipologia"=> "Complemento",
    "Pertenece"=> "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; ",
  ],
  [
    "Juego"=> "Snipter Ghost Warrior Pase de Temporada",
    "Tipologia"=> "Juego",
    "Pertenece"=> "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435957d4; ",
  ]
];
```

Puedes ordenar el array con una función definida por ti mismo:

```
usort($miarray,  function ($a, $b) {

    if ($a['Tipologia'] == $b['Tipologia']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['Tipologia'] < $b['Tipologia']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

La impresión del array mediante `print_r($miarray);` arrojaría

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Juego] => MK14 EBR & skins
            [Tipologia] => Juego
            [Pertenece] => 66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Juego] => Snipter Ghost Warrior Pase de Temporada
            [Tipologia] => Juego
            [Pertenece] => 66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435957d4; 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Juego] => Sniper Ghost Warrior 2 - Gold
            [Tipologia] => Complemento
            [Pertenece] => 66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Juego] => Limited Edition
            [Tipologia] => Complemento
            [Pertenece] => 66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; 
        )

)
```

Dependiendo de la función que definas en `ursort` puedes usar más criterios para cuando las tipologías sean iguales.

Fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22101943c5ebb9b56dd2d873c5290bf61a33b29b

Answer (score 0):

Puedes combinar [**`array_multisort`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php) y [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php) para ordenar por una clave determinada. Sería simplemente esto:

```
array_multisort ( array_column($mArray, 'Tipologia'), SORT_ASC, $mArray );
```

- `$mArray` es tu array
- `'Tipologia'` es la clave por la que quieres ordenar
- [`SORT_ASC`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php) es para indicar que quieres un orden ASCendente.

Siendo `$mArray` el array que presentas en la pregunta, luego de aplicar el código anterior, podemos probar el orden:

```
#Prueba
var_dump($mArray);
```

***Salida:***

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(15) "Limited Edition"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(11) "Complemento"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(29) "Sniper Ghost Warrior 2 - Gold"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(11) "Complemento"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(16) "MK14 EBR & skins"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(5) "Juego"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435907d4; "
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Juego"]=>
    string(39) "Snipter Ghost Warrior Pase de Temporada"
    ["Tipologia"]=>
    string(5) "Juego"
    ["Pertenece"]=>
    string(38) "66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802435957d4; "
  }
}
```